# How much caching we should do in microservice?

Tags: caching, microservices

I have been working on micro-service architecture for a e-commerce application. and I have used cache to reduce the service communication over wire and hence improve the application performance.

I am only storing the business entities like product and prices and some configuration level data.

But i am wondering how much data we should cache. What should be the max size of cache we should keep and some strategies around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right answer to it , it really depends on your use case and nature of data that you are caching. Modern architectures are serving all the static content (dyanmic in some cases as well) through CDNs. So long you are following good practices and know the limitations you are good.

Be aware cache is supplementary solution so you can't completely rely on on this. In terms of microservices/backend cache is temporary data store and if cache got any problems you may have to refill the cache from original data source again , during this time you may overload your original data source, you need to be sure if your data source is able to handle this kind of scenario and take the direct load?

I found some good practices here
[Caching Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching#considerations-for-using-caching)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Deep down i also knew that there is no right answer for this question. Its all about the data and application you are working on and also Thanks for the link this will help me to use caching efficiently.

Comment: Glad it helped. Throw me any questions if you would have . Cheers

Comment: Mark the answer if you think it helped you. It may be helpful for someone else who is looking for similar. Cheers!